# Copy in VBA info from one data sheet already open to other data sheet from other location

Tags: vba, copy

I want to copy dates from a sheet name MasterData which contain macro in a file sheet from other location name Data base .At the end I want to clear info from MasterData sheet and to close sheet Data base.
I run below code but nothing is happening.
Please can advise?
I'm kind new in running VBA code...
Thank you.
Mari

```
 Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()


Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\VBA\Test1\Prices_Database_ For_ Volume.xlsx"
  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MacroMaster file.xlsm").Sheets("MasterData")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ Volume.xlsx").Sheets ("DataBase")

    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Offset property moves down 1 row
```

lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

```
      wsCopy.Range("A2:AB100" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    'Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ Volume.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
   'Workbooks("MacroMaster file.xlsm").Worksheets("MasterData").Range ("A2:AB100").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Hope is more ok now

Comment: Can you please review the formatting of your post? Thank you.

Comment: Use 4 spaces at the beginning of the line for code.

Comment: I've just tried your code, and it works fine for me.. I suggest stepping through code `(F8)` and see if your variables/ranges are what you expect to be. While in step through, use your [immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window) and [quick watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/use-quick-watch). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello DarXyde - yes the code seems that work sometime but appear couple alerts when I open MacroMaster file.xlsm - like We can't update some of the links in your workbook right now...if I go with Continue appear a Type mismatch.. error.Please advise is not a problem that I copy data from Xlsm file in xlsx file?Or at what referring this error?Please advise.Thank you

Comment: This line `wsCopy.Range("A2:AB100" & lCopyLastRow).Copy` is incorrect; you can't copy a range and the last row. If you wanted to use the last row then; `Range("A2:AB" & lCopyLastRow)` or just use the range `A2:AB100`.

Comment: @GMalc You are correct that code needs to be written better, but you can still use it as it is, for example if `lCopyLastRow = 123` , then  `"A2:AB100" & lCopyLastRow` = "A2:AB100123"`. Still works, just not as intended.

Comment: Thank you very much, now seems to work much better with Range("A2:AB" & lCopyLastRow).Which is very logic. After all I can't take in range last column twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of your code with out all the variables. It incorporates the last rows into each range.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\VBA\Test1\Prices_Database_ For_ Volume.xlsx"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
    Range("A2:AB" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ Volume.xlsx").Sheets("DataBase").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
```